# How to use git with MVC pattern

Tags: php, git, model-view-controller

How to use git, when I have large tree of folders in file structure of web-project. Module, which I developing is separated by different folders in this file structure. As it is customary by MVC pattern concern.

In the overall file structure of web-project I have, roughly speaking:

- model folder
- controller folder
- views folder
- languages folder
- and so on

I making changes in files at this folders and need track changes. These folders are not combined in one folder, that associated with module, that I developing. These folders are scattered in different parts of the file structure.

I could create git repository at the root of file structure and in `.gitignore` specify, which folders track. But I develop many modules. And I need separate git repositories for them.

Where and how create git repositories to developing many modules in large file structure?

If I init git repository at the root of web-project is it possible to create many repositories at the root of file structure for each module and for each repository specify which folders git should track?

Comment: Depending on how you're working, might be worth having the modules in their own repositories outside of your main project and pulling them in via e.g. composer. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You have 2 options: 1 put your entire project in one repo. 2 as Jon said, create independant modules/libraries as their own repos and assemble your project with composer.

Comment: Could also use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest solution now days it's to keep your independent modules in separated repositories and then requesting them using [composer](https://getcomposer.org).

I will show you some theoretical example of it.

I have project, which should use Payment Module. Payment Module is a separated repository with `composer.json` file provided in root directory.

For example:

```
{
  "name": "company/payment-module",
  "description": "Module handling payments from our customers.",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Company\\PaymentModule\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

That gives you possibility of using any of modules created in any application/project you'll build. 
So, for example in your project you can require Payment Module as dependency.

```
{
  "name": "company/shop",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The main repository of our shop.",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/company/payment-module"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "company/payment-module": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

When you define modules you want in the project and install them using composer, they will be under `vendor/` directory and will be autoloaded into the namespaces you define.